# Automatically Scroll to a particular PHP message after click of a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my website ([Talklast.com](https://talklast.com/contact-us.php)) there's a contact page, and when users fill in the contact form and click on send a message using PHP is displayed which is done using echo.

So, I am trying to get users automatically scrolled to the message after the "Send" button is clicked, **In other words, I want to users to be automatically scrolled to a particular text after the click of a button (also, when the button is clicked, the page is reloaded).**

I was checking the below code I found in stack overflow, but it is not helping in my case -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#what').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

This is the PHP message I referred earlier (to which user should automatically scrolled to after the click of "Send" button -

```
<span style="color:green;"><?php if(isset($smsg)){ echo $smsg;}?></span>
```

Comment: You won't scroll to a "PHP message"... But to a HTML element rendered on the client-side. Reading [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set some selector to the `button` for uniquely identifying ( `id` or `class` ), then bind click event handler and do the rest within the handler. To scroll to the span give an `id` to the `span`  element and use that to scroll.

**JQuery :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // attached click event handler
  $('#button').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#span').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
  });
});
```

**Span:**

```
<span id="span" style="color:green;"><?php if(isset($smsg)){ echo $smsg;}?></span>
<!-- -^^^^^---- id --->
```

**Button :**

```
<button type="submit" name="send" id="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="padding: 3px 16px;" title="Click to send your message to Talklast.com">Send</button>
```

---

**UPDATE :** Set your form action as follows to scroll to the span when reloading.

```
<form action="#span" method="POST">
```

Ref : https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/190941?hl=en

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response.

But I'm wondering where to place this JQuery.!!! I placed it at the end (after </html>) but it didn't worked

Comment: @RajanSinha place it just before closing body tag

Comment: @RajanSinha `<script> /* ur code here */ </script></body></html>`

Comment: I added it before the closing </body> tag and included the <script>, but now when the page opens it directly scrolls to the area where the PHP message is to be displayed. I needed this automatic scrolling to happen after the user clicks the button ("Send" button in my case). Also, I checked and found that "$('#span').click(Function(){" line is not required

Comment: @RajanSinha :  I think there is duplicate code( maybe the code in your question ) present in your page, please check that... previously there was a typo in my code... i just fixed that now....

Comment: Yes, there is duplicate code (the PHP code I stated above, but have different echo messages) and also I gave different span id's to them and have created 2 different JQuery for them and have replaced the `span` with `#span1` and also in the `#what` I wrote span1 or span2 as required, but still it didn't work. Also, by keeping #what it didn't work. **The JQuery must scroll to the message only after the "Send" button is clicked**. Currently, it is happening before or after the button click.

Comment: You have to give id=span to the button then

Comment: Hey Pranav, Yes I updated my codes according to your latest updates. But, right now if I click on the "Send" button, the auto-scrolling is happening, but as discussed a click on "Send" button will result in reload of the page & after page reload the page is not scrolling to the message.

Comment: @RajanSinha : can you append something to the url while reloading ? If possible then append `#span`

Comment: @RajanSinha : or you have to do the form submission using ajax

Comment: Thanks Pranav, the addition of `<form action="#span" method = "POST">` solved the issue of not scrolling to the message after the page gets reloaded